# Error 5 error C2535 member function already defined or declared. VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm having some trouble with this code, my Visual Studio 2013 informs this error: "Error    5 error C2535 member function already defined or declared". I marked on code where exactly it happens.

```
#ifndef __NORMAL_H_INCLUDED__
#define __NORMAL_H_INCLUDED__

class Normal{

public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Normal(double x, double y, double z);
    Normal(double x, double y);
    Normal();
};

#endif
```

```
#include "Normal.h"

Normal::Normal(double x=0, double y=0, double z=0){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}


Normal::Normal(double x=0, double y=0){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = 0;
} // ERROR HERE = Error 5 error C2535 member function already defined or declared

Normal::Normal(){
    x=0;
    y =0 ;
    z =0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling your code with clang++ gives this error:

```
normal.cpp:12:23: error: addition of default argument on redeclaration makes this
      constructor a default constructor
Normal::Normal(double x=0, double y=0, double z=0){ 
                      ^ ~
normal.cpp:7:5: note: previous declaration is here
    Normal(double x, double y, double z);
    ^
normal.cpp:19:23: error: addition of default argument on redeclaration makes this
      constructor a default constructor
Normal::Normal(double x=0, double y=0){
                      ^ ~
normal.cpp:8:5: note: previous declaration is here
    Normal(double x, double y);
```

Which is probably a good way to say it. The compiler can't tell the difference between:

```
Normal n = Normal();
```

and

```
Normal m = Normal(0, 0);
```

or

```
Normal o = Normal(0, 0, 0);
```

If you always want the arguments to be zero filled, just use one form:

```
class Normal{

public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Normal(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0);
};
```

Never place default arguments in the implementation part, whether you have them in the header or not, since the temptation will be to change them in the implementation or header separately, and then you get VERY confusing results.

You may of course want to consider having the two or three different versions of constructor, and not have default values. But pick one of those two. Or use a constructor with one "has to have" value, and an "no values specified". Passing the arguments will of course add more code in the calling code, so in a large project, where `Normal` objects are created MANY times with different number of objects, there may be a significant difference in size between passing three `double` arguments and not passing any arguments.

I should add that the code compiles fine in `g++` version 4.8.2. Which is probably a bug...